# Converting Haml string to html

Tags: ruby, rubygems, haml

Could you tell me how to parse a haml string to html in rails?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
require 'haml'
Haml::Engine.new("%strong Yay for HAML!").render
```

Comment: Could you tell my how that works with mutli-line strings? %{asdasd...}?

Comment: HAML parses any string, including ones with multi-lines, but it would need to be properly indented with double spaces to not cause an error. Just put the multline string in a variable and pass it to it?

Comment: @Lichtamberg [Read about Ruby Strings](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/frameset.html?content=http%3A//phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html%23strings); @stef Haml also supports tabs as indentation, FWIW.

Comment: Tabs or spaces, either way HAML will reject the input if there's not white space ALA Python's indentation style.

Comment: also you can pass local variables: `world = 'world'; Haml::Engine.new('%b Hello #{world}').render(binding)`